# Deterministic and stochastic curves on the same plot in MATLAB using SimBiology Desktop

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, deterministic, stochastic

Can someone instruct me how to produce a plot consisting of number of stochastic curves combined with deterministic curve for the same set of chemical reactions only by using particular icons (tabs) in simbiology?

I know how to draw deterministic curve for particular model

- `(SimBiology:Model:Add Task:Simulate model, and then choose solver i.e. ode)`

And I know how to produce a bunch of stochastic curves

- `(SimBiology:Model:Add Task: Run ensemble simulation....)`

But I don't know how to merge these curves (`det.` and `stoch.`) into one plot.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of what you have so far, as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

- Add a Simuation Task to your project
- Turn on the live plots section (by clicking the Live Plots button in the toolstrip)
- Enable overlaying of results in the Live Plots (by right-clicking on the live plot and selecting the menu option "Overlay Results")
- Configure the simulation settings as desired (for example, click on the Simulation Settings button and switch between deterministic and stochastic solvers)
- Run the task
- Repeat the configuration and running of the task

You can find more information on the Live Plots [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simbio/ug/task-editor.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simbio/ug/running-tasks.html).